# How can I configure Terraform in Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I wanted to install Terraform using Azure VM and wanted to execute some Terraform code. How can I create a Terraform platform in Azure VM and how can I execute my code?

Comment: the same way you would locally

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Terraform in the Azure VM the same like install other software in it. The Terraform is an executable program. Just download the Terraform executable program. For example, in Linux, download the Terraform into a path that in the environment variable Path, just like the path `/usr/local/bin/`, then you can execute it globally. For more details, see [Install and configure Terraform to provision VMs and other infrastructure into Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-install-configure). And it also shows how to execute the Terraform code.